# Protocol checksum reverse engineering

Tags: math, cryptography, protocols, checksum, decoding

I'm trying to reverse engineer a protocol's checksum. It seems to be a 4-bit nibble-based protocol.
The following is a binary representation of a packet in the protocol:

```
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0010 1010 : 1001
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0010 1011 : 1010
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0010 1100 : 1111
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0010 1101 : 0000
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0010 1110 : 1101
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0010 1111 : 1110
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 0000 : 0100
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 0001 : 0011
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 0010 : 0010
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 0011 : 0001
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 0100 : 1000
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 0101 : 0111
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 0110 : 0110
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 0111 : 0101
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 1000 : 1100
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 1001 : 1011
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 1010 : 1010
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 1011 : 1001
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 1100 : 0000
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 1110 : 1110
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0011 1111 : 1101
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0100 0000 : 0101
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0100 0001 : 0110
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0100 0010 : 0111
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0100 0011 : 1000
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0100 0100 : 0001
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0100 0101 : 0010
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0100 0110 : 0011
1000 0001 1000 0001 0000 0001 1111 0100 0111 : 0100
```

The last nibble (after the ":") is some sort of checksum. I can't figure out how it's calculated. I'm not even sure if it takes all previous fields into account. Most (if not all) of the other 36 bits are part of a simple incrementing counter.

If anyone can help figure out what the algorithm used to calculate the csum, that would be greatly appreciated.

- Tom

Comment: Can you feed whatever you want into this to see how the checksums come out? If so, I recommend feeding in files with 2, 4, 8, and 16 lines, each of which is identically all 0s, then all 1s (a total of 8 files) and then compare the results. That should be more instructive than looking at the counter. I took a quick look and it looks like there is some kind of stair-stepping pattern going on but it does not appear to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, with the help from an anonymous person on IRC. Turns out it wasn't the full packet, there were more bits preceding it. After that it's a simple XOR of all values plus one mod 16.